# Adding a Parameter at End of all url matching a format through Htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

Pl advise

Pl advise, how to add Itemid=13 on end of all url matching by making 301 redirect

```
index.php?option=com_usedtoy&view=post&id=**variable**
```

For ex
Incorrect URL

```
 www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_usedtoy&view=post&id=495
 www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_usedtoy&view=post&id=497
 www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_usedtoy&view=post&id=510
```

Correct URL

```
 www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_usedtoy&view=post&id=495&Itemid=13
 www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_usedtoy&view=post&id=497&Itemid=13
 www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_usedtoy&view=post&id=510&Itemid=13
```

**HTACCESS CODE TRYING**

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)option=com_usedtoy(&|$) [NC]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)Itemid=13(&|$) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}/%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
 RewriteRule ^(index\.php)/(option=com_usedtoy&view=post)&(^id=.*)&((?!Itemid=13&).+)$ /$1?$2&Itemid=13&$3 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)option=com_usedtoy(&|$) [NC]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)Itemid=13(&|$) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}&Itemid=13 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks once again. It was pretty quick and right on spot.

Comment: btw you were fairly close to the answer as you can observe :)