# Redirect URLs with parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have URLs like

```
www.mysite.com/city/some-url-structure
```

I need to add parameters to the end of the URL like

```
www.mysite.com/city/some-url-structure?sort_value=distance
```

How do I make a rewrite rule in `.htaccess` file to get that?

Comment: You want to do the redirection in PHP?

Comment: @ChinLeung. Sorry, forgot to mention that, I need to do that in `.htaccess` file

Comment: have a look
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497326/adding-a-parameter-at-end-of-all-url-matching-a-format-through-htaccess

Comment: @urfusion. I need to add the query parameter along with `?` to a plain URL

Comment: try it
`RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING !?sort_value=distance
 RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /%1?%{QUERY_STRING}?sort_value=distance [L]`

I am not sure about this. It might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)sort_value=distance(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^city/some-url-structure/?$ %{REQUEST_URI}?sort_value=distance [L,NC,QSA,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: you are always right in `regex` and `htaccess`.. :)

Comment: Overboard with the flags a bit.

Comment: I think every flag has a reason to be there. I will be happy to remove them if any flag is not serving any purpose here.

Comment: @anubhava Don't really need QSA or NE, or possibly even NC. Also you need city at the start of rule.

Comment: Ah you're right, I overlooked that in question. Thanks.

Comment: `NC` is for ignore case, it is needed to redirect if client sends e.g. `CITY/...`. `QSA` is needed to preserve pre-existing query string if there is any. `NE` is to avoid encoding special characters in URL.

Comment: @anubhava I know what theyre for, just don't think they are needed for this rule.

Comment: As I commented all the flags are to serve some specific purpose. OP may or may not need them because `some-url-structure` is some generic phrase and we don't know what it would be. On the other side keeping these flag won't cause any harm that I can assure :)

Comment: `some-url-structure` is not a specific one. I think I need to make it `/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/` instead. But, Thanks! It helped